# How far in past windows 'Undo' operation works?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Recently, I used windows 10 'Undo' operation to recover recently deleted files. However, mistakenly I pressed 'Undo' button several time and later I found that some other files and folders disappeared due repeated 'Undo' operation. I want to know how far in passed time, this 'Undo' works because folders and files which I lost was created 3 hours back in time.

Answer (score 2):

Files normally stay in the Recycle Bin for 30 days and then they are deleted. So you can open the Recycle Bin and restore files for that time.  "Undo" works during your current session but if you do repeated "Undo" operations, it may be difficult to determine exactly what happened. I prefer to open the Recycle Bin and recover exactly what I need

Comment: ‘Undo’ operation did not move previously created folders/files into RecycleBin. ‘Undo’ operation removed files which were created before putting computer into sleep mode. I guess there is  some time span associated during which ‘Undo’ works.

Comment: "Undo" only last for the current session (log off or shut down). If you leave the computer ON all the time, then "Undo" can only go back through its thread of what you "did" first.